Play Console rejects app because of the server connection
My app fetches ics files from https://urnik.fov.um.si. This site could be loaded only in Slovenia, so I left only this country in the Region selection list. Google rejected this update and I got a screenshot where the app throws error "Unable to connect".
After that I decided to create an nginx proxy: I rent a server in Slovenia and set up an nginx reverse proxy: https://proxy.fov-calendar.com. I tested site availability with VPN of many European countries and it worked fine.
But play console still rejects my update and sending me the same screenshots with error. How can I establish a guaranteed connection to pass google tests?
Parser code:
Future<List<String>> fetchEventLines(String group) async {
  final url = 'https://urnik.fov.um.si/Program/calendars/$group.ics';
  final proxyUrl = 'https://proxy.fov-calendar.com/$group.ics';
  var result;
  try {
    result = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
  }
  catch(e) {
    result = await http.get(Uri.parse(proxyUrl));
  }
  if(result.statusCode != 200) {
    result = await http.get(Uri.parse(proxyUrl));
  }
  List<String> lines = const LineSplitter().convert(utf8.decode(result.bodyBytes));
  return lines;
}


